# How can I change jwplayer skin in og:video meta tag?

Tags: facebook, embed, facebook-opengraph, jwplayer, video-embedding

I would like to change default JW player(5.5) skin for facebook video embeds.
I start with this:

```
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" /> <meta property="og:video" content="https://www.neocsatblog.info/jwplayer/player.swf?file=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.neocsatblog.info%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F02%2FQNA.mp4&autostart=true&skinURL=http://neocsatblog.info/skinning-sdk/five/newtube/newtube.xml" />
```

But looks like when I debug the link and I would like to play the video, my skin just ingored and the default player loaded.

Comment: Since facebook.com is loaded via HTTPS, browsers will block all insecure content you try to load via HTTP only. Pretty sure your browser console should also contain a message in that regard.

Comment: Good tip, I chanced the skin url to https, but looks like also ignored

Comment: Any error message in the browser console? What does the network panel say? Have you updated Facebook’s cache of your URL via the debug tool?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't see any error.
Yes, I always delete link cache after I chanched something.
But here the link:
http://www.neocsatblog.info/ti-milyen-zenet-raktatok-volna-ez-ala-a-videom-ala/

Comment: Calling your player URL directly in my browser, I don’t see any difference, no matter whether I leave the parameter `skinURL` in or take it out. So what exactly is supposed to happen based on it?

Comment: If you setup the jw player in normaly (so not inline) `skinUrl` varible gived that skin for the player, what you setted.
Here the documentation:
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference#skin

Comment: That site talks about styling the player using CSS, which likely means it is applicable to situations where the player itself is rendered as mutiple HTML elements only. When embedding videos on Facebook, you/your player can not render any custom HTML, it allows for the embedding of an SWF flash file or an MP4 video directly only.

Comment: Is there anyway for change default skin?

Comment: Only if you have a flash player that handles its “skinning” _in_ flash as well.

Comment: In this article the post is sayed:
I can add more pramaters with `&` mark in here:
https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player/
That's not true for the 5 version?

Comment: Do you have the “proper cross-domain security restrictions in place”, as that document mentions?

Comment: So I need to add a `corss-domian.xml` file with a `&` parameter right?

Answer (score 0):

You can find info on CSS skinning the player here: http://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/css-skinning-reference.html

Comment: Unfortunately,  this is not a good answer, I have skin,  but I can't use in facebook page.

Comment: Is this loading properly on a static page? Want to make sure it's isolated to the Facebook embed.

Comment: Yes, it's can (I tested it), but I only use this player for facebook, becouse I dosen't know anything else which can work with Facebook perfectly fine.